# refresh the page until Browser able to connect to the server

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Hi I want to keep refreshing the browser until Firefox able to connect to the server. Below is my code which is expected to refresh until the element in the login page is found. But instead my test case is failing. Please help.

```
     do{
            driver.navigate().refresh();
         }
while(!(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/input")).isDisplayed()));
```

Comment: Instead of refreshing use wait method so that driver wait until the element is visible.

Comment: I specifically want to refresh because I am not sure of the waiting time, it may take between 5 mins to 15 mins.

Comment: actually you were looking for the element from the server/page. If you make a request then you will get the response. There is no point in refreshing the page. If you do so it actually mean that you are keep on requesting. Dont do refresh instead use the following wait method. 1. WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Register')]"))); 2. driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 3. Thread.sleep(10000);

Comment: @Das, Ahh, Actually the application is installing in the background. Once the installation is completed, I will be able to launch it via Web Browser.So I want to keep on refreshing the page until the software completed it's installation. The installation may take up to 5 mins to 10 mins. Until then When i launch the application via browser. I will get Not able to connect to the server. So I need to refresh the page for every 1 minute or refresh until the element is found in the browser

Comment: If so use Thread.sleep(300000); which is make waiting for 5min, I may be wrong with this so just give a try. If you found the answer pls share it.

Comment: this is my answer: Boolean elementFound = false;

        do {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            try {
                 elementFound = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/input")).isDisplayed();

            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e){
            }   
           driver.navigate().refresh();  

        } while (!elementFound);